# accessing a PHP variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

In my controller, I'm passing the image which is an array in this way:

```
$this->load->model('site_model');
$data['images'] = $this->site_model->fetch_images();
$data['main_content'] = 'my_view';
$this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
```

Everything up to know is perfect and even I can have the following in my view which shows the path of the first element:

```
echo $images[0]['path'];
```

But in view in script I'm trying to do the following which gives me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"`

```
  alert('<?PHP echo $images[0]['path']; ?>');
```

Why is that? Is not that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Use `alert(<?php echo json_encode($images[0]['path'] ?>);`.

Comment: what's in $images[0]['path'];

Comment: Where is your alert? in a php file or in a javascript file?

Comment: @MikeW The quotes are not the problem. PHP will parse whatever is in between the <?php ?> tag. The error here is most likely that the OP is trying to run php in a JS file and there is no substitution being made. hence the syntax error.

Comment: My alert is in my javascript tag in my PHP file

Comment: Open the page in the browser and check the generated source. Look for the alert and you will find your error.

Comment: thats the generated code: alert('C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\application\images\4.jpg');

Comment: Still I did not figure out the problem! Everything seems fine! :(

Comment: @user3421904: JS does special things with backslashes in strings.  You need to escape them.  Try `alert(<?= json_encode($images[0]['path']) ?>);`.

Comment: Man! You solved it! Could you please add it as a solution and I will solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you're outputting contains backslashes, which in JavaScript strings begin an "escape sequence" -- basically a typable representation of a character that otherwise you'd have trouble putting into a string.  But when they appear naked in a string, JS often chokes on them.

Rather than echoing the path directly, try this:

```
alert(<?= json_encode($images[0]['path']) ?>);
```

That will make PHP format the text in a way that'll cause fewer problems in JS.

(In some versions and configurations of PHP, `<?=` might not work.  You can use `<?php echo` in its place; it does the same thing.  It's just wordier.  :P )

Comment: Thanks for your nice solution and explanation :) I dont know whether I can ask one more question here as well or not; now in your code is there anyway if I replace 0 with the id of clicked button? in other words in your php tag which I have in my script tag again can I replace 0 with this.id ; here is my code:
        $('.btn').click(function(){       
            alert(this.id);
            alert(<?= json_encode($images[this.id]['path']) ?>);
        }) This one is another issue!

Comment: @user3421904: The PHP code runs on the server -- usually just once, when the page loads.  So the page would have to reload in order for the output to change.  You could dump a whole array of filenames, though, which `json_encode` handles just as well as strings...and then use JS to get the right value from the array depending on which button was clicked.

Comment: In newer versions of PHP, it might be something like `images = <?= json_encode(array_column($images, 'path')) ?>;` to dump an array of filenames.  Then you'd say `alert(images[this.id]);` to show the name corresponding to that button.

Comment: You are awesome man! Thanks for your patience! and solving my problem! :)

Comment: Interesting how that was my very first comment ;-)

Comment: @Jack: Heh...so it was.  Maybe mine got noticed due to the authoritative-sounding explanation.  :)

Comment: @cHao That must have been it =D

Comment: Oh yes your concept was right, but I just copied your code to test right away, it did not work; now I noticed your code had a syntax error; a closing parenthesis was missing; this one works: alert(<?php echo json_encode($images[0]['path']) ?>);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
alert("<?php echo $images[0]['path'] ?>");
```

or try putting you php variable into a Javascript variable

to do so simply:

```
var data = "<?php echo $images[0]['path'] ?>";

alert(data);
```

cheers!

Comment: Your solution did not work either! even the generated code seems fine ; the generated code is: alert('C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\application\images\4.jpg');

Comment: Tried double code and still no difference, but the generated code seems fine !

Comment: The problem i think is your backslash... because it is a escape string

Comment: try making your backslash to forward. or edit it to 

C:\/xampp\htdocs\myProject\application\images\4.jpg

Answer (score -2):

Try to JavaScript alert this way to store into $path variable,

```
$path = echo $images[0]['path'];
```

Now you print this $path into alert box

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("' . $path . '");</script>';
```

Comment: Check this updated answer

Comment: If this works, it'll be mostly due to the use of `"` rather than `'` -- and the problem would be the path containing an apostrophe, which is a bit unlikely.